# Что лучше использовать в приложениях WPF: Page-Frame или ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf

Я делаю страничные интерфейсы в связке UserControl-ContentPresenter.
Что с Page-Frame, что с UserControl-ContentPresenter всё работает замечательно. Но я неоднократно слышала, что лучше использовать второй вариант. Кто прав?
**Что из этого правильнее использовать?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если кратко, то `Page` являются грубым нарушением MVVM подхода, ибо это View слой, который не должен отвечать за другие слои. Если у вас в проекте не используется MVVM, вам хочется, чтоб лишь бы работало, не задумываетесь о производительности, то можете использовать страницы. Но если вы хотите как положено, с привязками и всеми другими фичами WPF, то стоит задуматься о MVVM подходе, что в итоге приведет к отказу в использовании `Page` и переходу на `UserControl` с `ContentPresenter`, ибо при их помощи вы без труда отделите UI от основной логики.

Также тут стоит почитать документацию и понять, что же может например [Page](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.page), увидим там следующее:

> Инкапсулирует страницу содержимого, к которой можно перейти и которая может размещаться в Windows Internet Explorer, NavigationWindow и Frame.

Как видите, страницы могут многое, но большинство вещей попросту бесполезны во многих проектах. И тут стоит задать себе вопрос: а нужно ли мне то, что я не буду использовать в полной мере?

---

Если чуть углубиться, то...
Смотрите, в WPF существует в основном два подхода проектирования:

1. Скажем так, базовый - это когда вы пишете проект и не задумываетесь о том, как оптимальней и лучше, когда используете в коде контролы (`myTextBox.Text = "Привер мир!"`), когда не задумываетесь о производительности, стиле и так далее. Многие новички так и поступают, верно? Только вот этот подход имеет ряд очень весомых проблем:

   1. Масштабируемость. Когда у вас в одном месте смешена работа и с UI и, например с базой, то дополнить или изменить что-либо бывает очень проблематично.
   2. Производительность. Когда вы напрямую дергаете UI элементы и не отделяете основную логику, ваше приложение затрачивает больше усилий на выполнения поставленной задачи.
   3. Такой подход нарушает всякие ООП и SOLID подходы, ибо опять же, у вас все вперемешку и вместо того, чтобы работать с данными, вы начинаете работать с UI.
2. MVVM - Суть этого подхода заключается в том, что весь проект разбивается на слабо связанные друг с другом слои (Model/ViewModel/View) и при помощи привязок и других механизмов, часть работы за нас вовсе делает сам WPF, нам надо ему лишь указать нужные данные и нужный вид отображения. Сами же данные разрабатываются таким образом, что мы вовсе не знаем, что у нас есть UI, будто у нас консольный проект, который должен выполнить заданную логику. То есть, в таком проекте у нас:

   - Model - отвечает за данные (работа с базой, сайтом, файлами и др.), он не знает что-либо про то, где будет использоваться, кем и когда, его задача просто выполнить свою логику и дать нам "интерфейс" управления, через который мы будем отправлять и получать данные в коде.
   - View - это интерфейс проекта (UI). Этот слой также вообще не знает про существование кого либо, он знает лишь что у `TextBox` должен быть такой-то стиль, а текст он должен взять из некого `{Binding T}`, где `T` - это некое абстрактное имя, которого может и не быть вовсе. То есть в View слое делается лишь дизайн приложения, но не логика.
   - ViewModel - слой, который общается с Model и реализует те самые "абстрактные имена" (свойства) для View слоя. Этот слой также не знает что-либо про View слой, про то, какой у приложения UI, он лишь дает данные и общается с Model, не более.

   Как видите, в MVVM подходе все разбивается на мелкие кусочки, некие модули, которые друг про друга толком и не знают, и вместо `myTextBox.Text = "Привет мир!"`, используется просто `Text = "Привет мир!"`, где `Text` - это некое свойство отдельного класса, класса, который отвечает за свою определенную ответственность. Тем самым, наш проект имеет ряд преимуществ:

   1. Расширяемость. Мы с легкостью можем изменить, добавить, удалить любую логику и это в большинстве случаев не потребует изменений в других слоях (дате или UI). А если еще и подключить допустим IoC подход, то модульность нашего проекта может очень сильно повыситься, и вместо того, чтобы разрабатывать один проект, мы в итоге будем разрабатывать отдельные подпрограммы, которые будет и проще отлаживать, и проще проектировать.
   2. Производительность. За счет того, что мы не оперируем постоянно с лишними данными, у нас чистые классы, которые выполняют только то, что нужно (а не подсчитывают за другими), мы выигрываем в скорости работы нашего приложения. Также, за счет привязок и другой "магии", за нас многое делает сам WPF (рисует интерфейс, обрабатывает события и многое другое).
   3. Соблюдение других фундаментальных правил (ООП, SOLID). MVVM подход отлично дополняет все эти правила, и мы без труда сделаем всякие "единственная ответственность", "открытость/закрытость" и др.

Как видите, совершенно два разных подхода и стиля проектирования, где в первом все дозволено, но потом не говорите, что вам трудно поддерживать проект и реализовать нужный функционал. А второй подход требует следовать правилам, которые в дальнейшем вам очень сильно сберегут как нервы, так и силы. И тут мы видим сразу то, что в MVVM мы не можем использовать UI в коде, это самое грубое нарушение его основных правил, а из-за этого, мы не можем так просто использовать `Page` и особенно `Frame`, ибо для него мы должны будем привязать свойство контента с типом `Page`, а это View слой. В итоге получаем, что VM знает про View.

Вообще, программирование, это некая вещь, которая у каждого своя. Думайте своей головой что лучше и как лучше, изучайте сами, попробуйте оба подхода, сравните и уже потом выберите как лучше поступить конкретно в вашей задаче. Все правила и подходы проектирования созданы для того, чтобы упростить жизнь, но это не значит, что им надо следовать на 100%.

Comment: Вообще `Page` можно и без нарушения MVVM прикрутить, правда придется слегка извратнуться с использованием кастомных `DependencyProperty`, а в остальном отличный ответ :)

Comment: @aepot Ну, написать много чего можно, из любой ситуации выкрутиться, только вот вопрос: а зачем? если есть нормальные, стандартные решения. Page для MVVM это все же костыли.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я сама после первой работы с page-frame отошла от него, т.к. было неудобно реализовывать на его основе интерфейс. Он подключал много разных функций, которые мне были не нужны, или их цель была конкретную задачу, а переопределять было муторнее, чем сделать собственный велосипед. Вы подтвердили мои догадки по этому поводу!