# Как из одной страницы обратится к элементам другой страницы?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть страница UsersPage и страница RegistrationPage

Как из страницы UsersPage отключить через нажатие на кнопку ввод в текстовое поле (которое находится в RegistrationPage)?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            RegistrationPage registrationPage = new RegistrationPage(null);
            registrationPage.tBLoginReg.IsReadOnly = true;


            Navigation.startFrame.Navigate(new RegistrationPage((sender as Button).DataContext as Users));

        }
```

Параметры страницы

```
 public partial class RegistrationPage : Page
{
   

    private Users _currentUser = new Users();

    public RegistrationPage(Users selectedUsers)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (selectedUsers != null)
            _currentUser = selectedUsers;

        DataContext = _currentUser;

        cBRole.ItemsSource = LibraryEntities.GetContext().Role.ToList();

       
    }
    .........
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что это WPF (судя по вашим предыдущим вопросам), а значит я вам настоятельно советую поизучать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228886/220553), а также понять как устроен WPF, понять что там основным принципом являются привязки, которые вы игнорируете...

Comment: Но а в c# как это сделать ?

Comment: C# это язык, а WPF, WinForms, это фреймворки, которые разработаны для определенных задач. WPF - это XAML разметка и привязки, если вы их не используете, вы, страдаете (как сейчас). У вас должно быть свойство (`public bool IsActive {get;set;}`), дальше оно должно быть привязано к нужным элементам (`<Button IsEnabled = "{Binding IsActive}"/>`), все, дальше просто задаете этому свойству нужное значение и WPF делает все за вас. Поймите вы это наконец, станет в разы проще!

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться в коде одной страницы работать с другой страницей точно так же, как не хочется в одном методе работать с локальными переменными другого метода. Отделите контент от представления и вынесите его в отдельную структуру данных, которую передавайте в UI через DataContext.

Comment: @VladD говорит о шаблоне проектирования MVVM, если что.