# Как сделать навигацию в WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

У меня есть `ItemsVM` при нажатии на элемент я обрабатываю его в нем `ClickHandler`. Дальше я хочу открыть новое окно в зависимости от элемента. При обработке нажатия, я получаю из бд некоторую информацию(допустим Id). Дальше нужно как-то передать в `ElementVM` `Id` и создать Page(или datatemplate). Очевидно что нужно поменять VM c `ItemsVM` на `ElementVM`. Принцип похожий как гиперссылки в браузере, мы нажимаем на ссылку нам выдает новую страницу. В CodeBehind все пусто. Это вакуумный код для понимания.

*Если у вас есть свои реализации или предложение отправляйте*

**MainWindows.xaml**

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,-3" Background="#FFC8E4FF">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       
        <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="117,70,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding GetItems}"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="248" FontSize="22" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="#FF2558F0" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="373"        
                  >

            <ListView.DataContext>
                <vm:ItemsVM></vm:ItemsVM>
            </ListView.DataContext>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="118" Width="226" Background="#FF9C9C9C" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                        <Grid.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"
                                         Command="{Binding DataContext.DelegateCommands,
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            </MouseBinding>
                        </Grid.InputBindings>

                      


                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="16,10,10,68"  Background="#FFEDFFD6" FontSize="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Id}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="62,60,63,10"  FontSize="20" Background="#FFF4FFD6" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

**ItemsVM.cs**

```
  class ItemsVM : ViewModel
    {
        public ICommand DelegateCommands { get => _DelegateCommands; }

        private ICommand _DelegateCommands;
        
        /// <summary>
        ///  обработка нажатия
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void ClickHandler(dynamic e)
        {
            int id = e.Id;
            string name = e.Name;

            // Дальше делаю SELECT из бд и получаю подробную информацию

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Получаю коллекцию элементов для отображения и делаю binding
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<Item> GetItems
        {
            get
            {
               return new ObservableCollection<Item>{ new Item("A",1), new Item("B",2), new Item("C",3) };
            }
        }
        public ItemsVM()
        {
            _DelegateCommands = new DelegateCommand(o => ClickHandler(o));
        }
    }
```

**Item.cs**

```
 class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Item()
        {

        }
        public Item(string name,int id)
        {
            Name = name;
            Id = id;
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
 abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
        {
            add
            {

            }
            remove
            {

            }
        }



        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string PropertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
            return true;
        }
        private bool _Disposed;
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
        public void Dispose(bool Disposing)
        {
            if (!Disposing || _Disposed) return;
            _Disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

**DelegateCommand.cs**

```
  class DelegateCommand : ICommand
    {

        Action<object> execute;
        Func<object, bool> canExecute;


        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = this.AlwaysCanExecute;
        }

        public DelegateCommand()
        {

        }

        public void Execute(object param)
        {
            execute(param);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object param)
        {
            return canExecute(param);
        }


        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }


        private bool AlwaysCanExecute(object param)
        {
            return true;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Вы много делаете лишних действий, местами даже нарушаете MVVM. Ну а по вопросу - я немного не понял что вы хотите, открыть новое окно с нужными данными, или внутри одного окна сменить содержимое? И то и много раз обсуждалось тут, на SO.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну мне это надо в одном окне, в интернете не находил, то как я хотел сделать. Думал что это ситуация достаточно распространенная. А делать одну VM для обработки всего это не правильно, разве нет?

Comment: Кто сказал про одну VM? Правила SOLID не отменяли вроде, SRP - одна задача = один метод/класс. Также и тут, все по своим M, VM и V. Вот самый простой (и лучший) вариант [отображение разного содержимого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553), а вот почему [page это не MVVM и вообще плохо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228886/220553). Ну а также, советую ознакомится с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553), чтоб понять почему `<vm:ItemsVM></vm:ItemsVM>` плохо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: @aepot это не то что мне нужно

Comment: Как вы это поняли?

Comment: @aepot У меня задача немного другая. В вашем примере просто навигация по приложению. Мне, как я уже писал нужно иначе сделать. Если есть предложения как поменять мою логику то пишите

Comment: Я пока не понимаю, что именно вам нужно. Не в смысле войны с классами, которая подробно расписана, а в смысле, что же именно в окне должно происходить. Если сменить вьюху при клике на что-либо где-либо, то мое решение легко с этим справится. Но я не намерен вас уговаривать.

Comment: @aepot если взять мой xaml то будет в ListView элементы. Когда я на один из них нажимаю, то будет открываться новая вью. Но, как я писал выше то нужно еще получить инфу о том что это за элемент(на который мы нажали). Шаблон для странички одинаковый только текст будет разный. Аналогия закладки в браузере, мы нажимаем и открывается сайт

Comment: Ну, не вижу ни одной причины, по которой вы решили, что решение не подходит. Ну ок, вам виднее.

Comment: @aepot Хорошо, как можно тогда обработать нажатие в одной VM и при переходе на другую VM передать информацию?

Comment: VM либо уже содержит информацию, либо знает где ее взять. С точки зрения View, VM это и есть информация. Как сделать переключение View в зависимости от типа VM, я уже вам показал. А как обновлять данные без смены View - вы уже знаете - INotifyPropertyChanged. Привяжите часть View окна к свойству главной VM, создайте для нее шаблон. Команда будет только заниматься присваиванием свойства. Ну или вообще без команды, а так как показано в примере с привязкой SelectedItem. Это должно быть просто, вы запутались, распутывайтесь.

Comment: @aepot -"VM либо уже содержит информацию, либо знает где ее взять". У меня 2 VM, одна обрабатывает(ItemsVM) другая формирует(ElementVM) страницу на основе данных из ItemsVM. Как тогда последовательно вызвать обработчик нажатия в ItemVM и передать все в ElementVM, при этом создать новую страницу?

Comment: @aepot или такая логика будет неправильной по отношение к MVVM?

Comment: MVVM - это шаблон проектирования, он не отвечает за логику приложения. Он отвечает за разделение внутренней логики и представления, то есть интерфейса, а так же отделение от всего этого логики работы с данными. За счет этого обеспечивается модульность приложения, как следствие этого - приложение легче дорабатывать. Как именно логически ведут внутри себя эти разделенные части, MVVM не отвечает.

Comment: @aepot ну тогда как сделать что я выше написал, когда я запустил ваш код у меня появляется 2 окна и второе что мне мешает это то что 2 две мои VM не связаны интерфейсом, и скорее всего не должны у них только общий абстрактный класс

Comment: Классика, откройте App.xaml и уберите SrartupUri оттуда, вы были недостаточно внимательны.

Comment: @aepot действительно не обратил внимание, но это ничего не меняет, я все так же откладываю решение и делаю что-то другое. Есть ли вообще способ реализовать это

Comment: Дело ваше. Не планировал вас уговаривать.

Comment: @aepot Спустя месяц я отложил решение и до сих пор не могу решить эту проблему. Не могли бы написать пример реализации того что я описал выше

Comment: Вам уже даны все примеры в ссылках выше.

Comment: @aepot а если они не подходят под данную модель логики.

Comment: @aepot Я не понимаю как мне можно передавать информацию при переходе на новую страницу. Я же должен как-то фиксировать какой элемент я выбрал. И в соответствии формировать определенную информацию о нем.

Comment: @aepot Повторю для понимания, что это как в интернет магазине. Когда нажимаете на товар, то открывается полная информация о нем. Тут у меня есть элементы, при нажатии на них у меня формируется страница с полной информации про них.

Comment: Ну так тайл товара и страница товара могут формироваться из одной и той же вьюмодели. Одна вьюмодель, разные view. Вы просто меняете VM страницы с товарами на VM товара, по которому ткнули, и готово. Как сменить View в зависимости от выбранной VM, как раз и показано выше. С чего вы решили, что ссылки выше не несут никакой пользы - мне не понятно. Складывается впечатление только о том, что вы посмотрели, не захотели разбираться и закрыли предложенные решения. Как я выше написал, ваше право отказаться и разработать собственное, более понятное решение. Здесь я ничем помочь не могу.

Comment: @aepot С ссылками я ознакомился просто мне не понятно как добавить в них то что я хочу сделать. А именно как при нажатии я могу получить информацию о элементе(такой метод реализован) и при этом передать следующей Vm в формировании страницы. Если я буду менять vm то смысл тогда формировать все в одной(и разве не нарушает принцип SOLID) . Я видимо что-то плохо понимаю.

Comment: Вам дали методику, а не решение. Есть разница. Решение вы берете и копируете себе в проект, а методику думаете как применить к своему собственному решению. SOLID здесь вообще не при чем. Вам решать, как будет устроена архитектура решения. Где нарушать и где не нарушать - тоже вам решать.

Comment: @aepot ну если я хочу для решения задачи использовать разные vm, то как мне сделать то что я выше описал. Передавать информацию и что бы все было последовательно

Comment: Создать новую VM передав ей ссылку на Model с данными? Но для меня загадка, в чем смысл делать разные VM для одних и тех же данных.

Comment: @aepot если у меня разные VM то как их поместить в  PageViewModels?

Comment: Унаследовать общий интерфейс или базовый класс. ООП вас спасет.

Comment: @aepot в примере у вас отдельно навигация и интерфейс. У меня это все идет в ListView>Grid. И когда я нажимаю на элемент нужно открыть один и тот же шаблон просто с разной информацией в зависимости от нажатого элемента