# Навигация в многостраничном и многооконном приложении WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, page

У меня есть приложение в котором на данный момент есть 2 окна(окно регистрации-авторизации и главное окно), в окне авторизации-регистрации есть 3 страницы между которыми нужно свободно перемещаться(из 1 в 2, из 3 в 1 и т.д), навигация по страницам главного окна должна работать по такому же принципу. Как правильно и с помощь чего можно это реализовать.

Ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забудьте про [Page в MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228886/220553) проекте, оперируйте [VM уровнем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553), этого достаточно для большинства задач!

Comment: [Пример многостраничного окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо! Буду разбираться.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо!

Comment: Самый лучший способ - использование Prism/ReactiveUI. Основная идея - разбивка окна на области. В каждую область можно как подгрузить любой UserControl, так и выгрузить. Плюс из коробки есть возможность навигации вперед/назад.

Comment: @Denis Я не сижу на киберформе, по этой причине я не вижу изображений что там прикреплены, а текста ошибки я не увидел. Да и как-то не красиво отсылать на чужой ресурс, чтоб вам дали решение тут, не кажется? Ну ок, судя по коду вам пишет что-то по типу "не удалось найти namespace vm" (или что-то такое). Вот вам ваш код: `vm:AuthorizationViewModel`, что такое `vm` вы знаете?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, добавил изображения с ошибками к вопросу. Нет, что такое 'vm' не знаю

Comment: @Denis А что такое `namespace` (пространство имен) знаете?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да знаю, но не совсем понимаю как в xaml работает.

Comment: @Denis ну раз знаете, то объяснить будет проще. `vm` - это пространство имен, из которого будет браться следующее после `:`, скажем так, `vm:AuthorizationViewModel` - аналогичен `Frontend.ViewModel.AuthorizationViewModel` (или где там у вас нужный .cs) в простом c#, только весь `namespace`, в XAML, выносится отдельно как строки `xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Frontend.View.Controls.AuthorizationRegistration"` в начале, где `view` - это некий "ключ", через который обращаетесь (`view:...`), а все после `=`, это сам `namespace`. Собственно ваша ошибка в том, что вы не определили `vm`.

Comment: код или разметку лучше вставлять текстом, а не скринами. Проверьте, что написано у вас в строке `namespace` в коде. Оно должно совпадать с тем что вы пишете в xmlns строке. Так же попытайтесь собрать приложение, бывает так, что до сборки ошибка есть, а после сборки - нет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, добавил, дважды пересобрал и ошибки исчезли. Спасибо за объяснения и терпение.

Comment: @Denis Да не за что. Вам кстати выше про Prism писали, и судя по скринам и `Frontend` вы разбиваете все на мелкие составляющие. По этому советую хотяб мельком посмотреть [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278817/220553) подход. Но советую применять его после того, как поймете основу MVVM, привязок и самого c#.