# DataContext в C#

Tags: c#, wpf, классы, frame

На главном окне есть DataContext со статичным ресурсом ViewModelLocator и фрейм с Binding

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}" x:Class="SystemBackdropTypes.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SystemBackdropTypes"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:SystemBackdropTypes.ViewModels"
        Background="Transparent"
        Title="DWM System Backdrop Type Sample" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        mc:Ignorable="d">



    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="_this" Content="{Binding PageSource}" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
```

Как это всё написать на C#?
Мне нужно получить PageSource из MainViewModel и загрузить в фрейм

MainViewModel:

```
using DevExpress.Mvvm;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using SystemBackdropTypes;
using SystemBackdropTypes.Pages;
using SystemBackdropTypes.Services;

namespace SystemBackdropTypes.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private readonly PageService _pageService;

        public Page PageSource { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel(PageService pageService)
        {
            _pageService = pageService;


            _pageService.OnPageChanged += (page) => PageSource = page;
            _pageService.ChangePage(new LoginPage());
        }
    }
}
```

Я пытался сделать что-то типа:

```
_this.Content = DataContext.PageSource;
```

и

```
Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(_this, Frame.ContentProperty);
_this.Content = binding.Source;
```

Я новичок в WPF, так что строго не судите)

Comment: Если вы новичок, то я очень сильно советую вам отказаться от **всех** фреймворков, которые вы думаете, что "облегчат вам жизнь". Ведь вы даже не знаете как это все работает, но уже говорите о "локаторе"... Так что, удаляйте `DevExpress.Mvvm`, он вам сейчас лишь навредит. Далее, `DataContext со статичным ресурсом` - это [плохо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553), ведь окно не должно быть ответсвенным за создание данных, также не должно быть зависимо от данных. Далее, `Loaded="Window_Loaded"` - не лучшая идея в MVVM подходе, ибо при этом подходе все события меняются на комманды.

Comment: Ну и последнее - `Page`, этот контрол не предназначен для тех целей, которые вы хотите. Почему? Писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228886/220553). Так что, сейчас вы делаете не совсем то, что нужно. Хотите разного содержимого окна - вам [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553). Ну и старайтесь максимально отвязать UI (View) от данных (Model/ViewModel).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо. Есть какой ни будь пример реализации на github'e? И как сохранять состояние страницы и как в неё передавать переменные?

Comment: Пример чего вам надо? Страниц? Тут на SO таких ответов полно. И да, в WPF нету "форм", тут "окна", совсем другая штука. И прочитайте еще раз мой комментарий выше - вы должны максимально отделить данные от UI. Работайте с классами, вот как бы вы сделали все это в простом консольном проекте? Вот тут тоже самое, только `Console.WriteLine()` заменяете на свойства, к которым в дальнейшем привязываете UI. Поэтому, сохранение данных и передача - это вопросы из разряда "как мне сохранить состояние класса и как мне передать в него данные", а на них я думаю вы знаете ответ, не так ли?

Comment: Многостраничный пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567, подписываюсь под всем что выше. :)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а всё же. Можете ответить на мой вопрос?

Comment: А я вам не ответил на вопрос? Вроде все разжевал, дал ссылки полезные, сказал куда двигаться. Вам вон даже полноценный пример кинули многостраничного интерфейса, чего вы еще то хотите?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня в свойстве фрейма Content есть "{Binding PageSource}" которое зависит от DataContext. Как то же самое написать в коде C#? Просто интересно, гугл не особо помог

Comment: Я не понимаю ваш вопрос. Я вам выше написал, что вы максимально должны в WPF проекте отделить UI от данных, сказал как должно быть, даже код во вам дали. А вы сейчас берете и спрашиваете "а как мне в коде указать Content". Ну берите, задавайте имя фрейму (`x:Name`) и обращайтесь через него в C# коде (`myName.Content = PageSource`). Но делаете вы ерунду.