# Как переключиться на другую страницу и передать ей объект

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6

Задача - переключиться на другую страницу (например Page1.xaml) с главного окна.
Весь мозг сломал, пока ничего не нашёл.

```
//Такое не срабатывает
Page1 page1 = new Page1();
page.show();
```

Очень прощу помочь. Градус ненависти в крови скоро уйдёт в переполнение буфера...)

Comment: В WPF проекте `Page`, не лучшая идея (можете почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228886/220553)). Советую освоить [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553) подход, привязки, `UserControl`, `XAML`.

Comment: Чтобы показать `Page`, вам нужен контрол `Frame` в разметке. Насколько я помню, то как-то так: `myFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));`. Но именно в WPF рекомендую делать [как-то так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567).