# wpf Свойство CurrentPage в MainViewModel - нарушение MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, page

Сразу скажу, что я знаю про то, что для навигации можно (и нужно?) использовать Юзер Контролы, про них речь также пойдет ниже.

Итак, у меня есть 5 Page, которые уже готовы к использованию и мне нужно теперь их впихнуть в главное окно. Собственно для реализации навигации у меня есть 2 идеи, а потому 2 вопроса.

---

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что хранить путь к Page в свойстве CurrentPage в ViewModel главного окна - нарушение MVVM?

У меня есть несколько кнопок, к которым привязана команда смены страницы и в параметре команды я передаю путь к странице:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ChangePage}" СommandParameter="Pages/CoordinatesPage.xaml"/>
```

И есть команда и свойство CurrentPage:

```
private RelayCommand changePage;
public RelayCommand ChangePage
    {
        get
            {
                return changePage ??
                  (changePage = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                  {
                      CurrentPage = obj.ToString();
                  }));
            }
        }

        private string currentPage;
        public string CurrentPage
        {
            get { return currentPage; }
            set { currentPage = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
```

И, наконец, фрейм для отображения страницы:

```
<Frame Source="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

Хранение пути к странице в ViewModel - это хранение информации о View, а значит мне лучше сделать навигацию 2 способом?

---

2. Все, что мне нужно - это поменять в XAML Page на UserControl и уже использовать юзер контролы?

Я никогда не работал с юзер контролами ранее и начал делать страницы в виде Page, правильно ли я понимаю, что если я изменю Page на UserControl в XAML разметке то все будет работать так же, как и до этого?

Comment: Тут ответ максимально прост: Сам **Frame** не пригоден для MVVM (если это конечно ванильный), с некими доработками можно придумать, включая Page и все остальное, что связано с ним. Почитайте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228886/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ сделал как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763691/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b5-wpf-mvvm/765122#765122) , такой вопрос, как теперь переключаться между контролами? `<Button Command="{Binding ChangePage}" CommandParameter="{x:Type vm:CoordinatesViewModel}">` и `CurrentContentVM = obj;` в команде не работают (а точнее в контент презенторе выводит строчку а не контрол)

Comment: Если выводит вам строчку, а не контрол, то еще раз прочитайте ответ, начиная с `Ваш XAML будет выглядеть так:`

Comment: Еще пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567