# Как убрать панель перехода между страницами?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

[image: Чертова панель]

При нажатии на кнопку с переходом на другое окно\страницу, высвечивается вот эта панель с функционалом(переход между окнами)

ShowsNavigationUI = false; в коде не помог и в xaml коде тоже.

Может кто сталкивался с таким, но я понятия не имею как она появляется и как ее убрать, видимо прописана в Material Design, в разработке окна не отображается, в коде я ее не прописывал.

Comment: Не использовать `Frame` [вовсе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228886/220553)?) Будет сразу счастье.

Comment: Еще такое есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567, а вообще как-тоя отключал это на фрейме, только главное не перепутайте, фреймом у вас может быть само окно.

Comment: додумал, с вашей помощью же, спасибо!
Делаю проект с пейджами, страница регистрации выводилась во фрейм, который был создан в главном окне(позади страницы регистрации). Там нашел фрейм и вписал NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden". Панель сверху пропала, извиняюсь за свой затуп...