# Что правильней использовать в uwp c# приложениях для отображения информации и навигации между view?

Tags: mvvm, uwp

1. Правильней для отображения view использовать page и Frame.Navigate или нужно создавать свои view, наследовать для них userControl, а навигацию между view прописать в ViewModel?
2. Можно ли во Frame.Navigate передавать в качестве Объекта модель представления?
3. Использование Frame.Navigate в code-behind по событию нажатие кнопки является нарушением MVVM?

Comment: Ответ:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1228870/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-wpf-page-frame-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-contentpresenter

Comment: а нет, пред коммент для wpf.
вот это правильный ответ для uwp: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75919344/navigation-in-uwp-c-sharp