# WPF Переключение между Главным Окном и Страницей

Tags: wpf

Приложение начинается с Главного Окна. В нём есть 2 кнопки, по нажатии на которые открываются соответствующие страницы:

```
<Button Background="{DynamicResource Secondary}" Foreground="{DynamicResource Primary}" Content="De/Serialization Library" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="70" Padding="5"/>
        <Button Background="{DynamicResource Primary}" Foreground="{DynamicResource Secondary}" Content="Interface Styles Library" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="70" Padding="5" Click="Button_Click"/>

<Frame x:Name="Frame" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
```

Здесь, например, по нажатию на вторую кнопку, меняется контент у Frame, накладывая сверху нужную страницу. (Может есть способы лучше?):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Frame.Content = new ThemesPage();
}
```

Также, у ThemesPage.xaml есть кнопка, которая должна вернуть в главное окно для выбора:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="2" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Grid}" Background="{DynamicResource Primary}">
            <Image x:Name="Calendar_Icon" Source="/icons/стрелка влеов.png" />
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>

<Frame x:Name="Frame" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

**Как это следует реализовать нормально? Огромное спасибо, кто может помочь**

Comment: `Frame` не лучший выбор для реализации страниц ([почему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228886/220553)). Заменой будет простой [ContentPresenter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553), который отлично подходит под MVVM (которому вы вроде следуете). Вообще, в MVVM проекте старайтесь не использовать `x:Name` (если только не в стилях), и всякие события по типу `Click` (заменяйте их на команды).

Comment: Спасибо большое!