# Многостраничность WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Реализация MVVM проекта. У меня есть главное окно MainWindow.xaml, код ниже. В нём, как видно есть Frame, принимающий значение переменной в качестве контента. Изначально в окне устанавливается главная страница. По нажатию на кнопку должна срабатывать команда, которая открывает другую страницу. Также должен быть переход данных, в данном случае на главной странице есть поле для ввода города, эта строка должна переходить на вторую страницу для дальнейней работы:

```
<Grid>
        <Frame
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Grid.RowSpan="3"
            Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"
            NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
            Opacity="{Binding Opacity}"
            />
</Grid>
```

Соответственно для окна указал контекст данных:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
```

MainViewModel:

```
internal class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedHelper
    {
        private Page MainPage, WeatherInfo;
        
        private Page currentPage;
        public Page CurrentPage
        {
            get { return currentPage; }
            set
            {
                currentPage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private double opacity;
        public double Opacity
        {
            get { return opacity; }
            set
            {
                opacity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        /*public ICommand WeatherCityCommand { get; set; }*/
        public ICommand WeatherCityCommand { get; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            MainPage = new View.MainPage();
            WeatherInfo = new View.WeatherInfPage();
            WeatherCityCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenWeatherWindow);

            Opacity = 1;
            CurrentPage = MainPage;
        }

        public void OpenWeatherWindow()
        {
            CurrentPage = WeatherInfo;
        }
    }
```

**Команда в принципе не срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку, поэтому окно не открывается. Что я делаю не так?**
MainPage.xaml:

```
<TextBox
                    materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True"
                    FontFamily="Jura"
                    Background="{DynamicResource Secondary}"
                    Foreground="{DynamicResource BackgroundText}"
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    Height="25"
                    Width="174"
                    Margin="17,15,15,0"
                    FontSize="15"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Ваш город"/>

                <Button FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Jura" Content="Узнать погоду" Background="{DynamicResource Focus}" Foreground="{DynamicResource BackgroundText}" Margin="17,24,15,17" FontSize="15" Cursor="Hand" Height="25"
                  Width="174"
                  Command="{Binding WeatherCityCommand}">
                </Button>
```

Сроки горят, был бы благодарен за быстрый и ценный ответ :)

Comment: У вас два существенных нарушения MVVM: 1. `DataContext = new MainViewModel();` - у вас View слой отвечает за создание, срок жизни, и др. ViewModel слоя, когда по правилам MVVM эти слои вообще не должны знать ничего про друг друга ([подробней](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553)).  2. `Page` - это UI элемент, а UI по правилам MVVM должны быть в ViewModel слое? Нет. И тут мы понимаем, что [Frame не для MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228886/220553), хотите правильно, используйте [ContentPresenter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553).

Comment: Теперь ваша основная проблема: Вот смотрим `Command="{Binding WeatherCityCommand}"`, где у вас `WeatherCityCommand`? В `MainViewModel`, ок... А `DataContext` у `MainPage` какой? Вы его задали? Я этого не вижу. Думаю ошибку поняли?) Устранить это просто, либо укажите `DataContext`, либо передайте ссылку на `MainViewModel`, сохраните ее в свойство внутри страницы и привязку используйте как `{Binding Свойство.WeatherCityCommand}`, но думаю понимаете, что вы UI элементом оперируете в VM слое, нарушая MVVM?

Comment: Я немного переделал, так как перечитал ТЗ. В приложении должно быть 2 окна, вот как раз в MainWindow у меня главное окно, а в WeatherInfWindow - второе. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажати на кнопку в первом окне, в том же открывалось второе, чтобы короче говоря не создавалось второе окно отдельно, вот MainViewModel:

Comment: private UIElement windowContent;
        public UIElement WindowContent
        {
            get { return windowContent; }
            set
            {
                windowContent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string city;
        public string City
        {
            get { return city; }
            set
            {
                city = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: public ICommand OpenSecondWindowCommand { get; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            OpenSecondWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenSecondWindow);
        }

Comment: private void OpenSecondWindow()
        {
            /*WeatherInfWindow secondWindow = new WeatherInfWindow(City) { DataContext = this };
            WindowContent = secondWindow;*/

            WeatherInfWindow weatherWindow = new WeatherInfWindow(City) { DataContext = this };
            WindowContent = weatherWindow.Content as UIElement;
            weatherWindow.Show();

            Application.Current.MainWindow.Hide();
        }

Comment: Возможно ерунду пишу, просто тороплюсь очень

Comment: Создать окно по правилам MVVM это еще тот гемор) Помним ведь, что View не должен знать ничего про VM, а VM не должен знать про View, это самое базовое правилом MVVM, ну а окно это что? Правильно, View (UI) слой, а это значит, что мы не можем просто так взять и в VM слое его создать. Тут нужна некая абстракция, некая обертка над окнами, которая будет где-то за пределами всех слоев оперировать окнами, задавать `DataContext`, открывать их. Вот [одна из реализаций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/220553), где по VM некий отдельный класс будет создавать окна, в VM у вас только VM будут.