# Отрисовка страниц на WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Создаю приложение, и не могу понять вроде делал по инструкции с гайда в интернете, но переключение страниц не работает, при нажатии кнопки, подскажите пожалуйста:
Сама функция переключения:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using PCheck.View;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace PCheck
{
    internal class ViewMainModal : ViewModelChangings
    {
        private Page _startPage = new StartPage();
        private Page _diagnosticPage = new DiagnosticPage();
        private Page _mainPage = new MainPage();

        public Page _CurPage
        {
            get => null;
            set => Set(ref _startPage, value);
        }

        public ICommand OpenStartPage
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() => _CurPage = _startPage);
            }
        }
        public ICommand OpenDiagnosticPage
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() => _CurPage = _diagnosticPage);
            }
        }
        public ICommand OpenMainPage
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() => _CurPage = _mainPage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И так же Xaml где находится следующие основные элементы, это кнопка по которой идёт переключение,frame в котором будет появляться окно и объявление где хранится и какая функция используется

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewMainModal d:IsDataSource="True"/>
</Window.DataContext>
    xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:PCheck.View"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PCheck"
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding OpenStartPage}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="774,457,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Transparent" Height="52" Width="208" FontFamily="Rostelecom Basis" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="17" Background="#FFFD4E1F" Foreground="{x:Null}" Cursor="Hand" Click="Button_Click_4">
    <Frame x:Name="MainFraime" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Content="{Binding _CurPage}" Navigated="MainFraime_Navigated"/>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: Если прямо про этот код, вы не можете созданные страницы хранить, вы можете их только создавать, потому что использованная страница, с которой вы уходите, уничтожается. Правильно вот так `new RelayCommand(() => _CurPage = new MainPage());` Но это не решение, если вы собираетесь или используете MVVM, так как оно нарушает MVVM. Решение в предыдущем комментарии, по ссылке.

Comment: Советую почитать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228886/220553) и [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553)

Comment: aepot,
Получается изменил на ваш код , всё-равно ничего не происходит

Comment: А суть сохранения нужна была для сохранения данных которые вводит пользователь и не стирать их, так же появляются элементы , которые как бы уникальные и должны оставаться

Comment: Ваши данные должны быть в VM/Model слое, но не в View слое, ну а `Page` является View слоем. Другими словами, у вас у каждой страницы должна быть своя VM, которая не должна находиться в XAML, а создаваться также, отдельно, и вот уже она должна храниться. Если бы у вас использовались DI контейнеры (советую кстати), то ваша задача решилась бы просто - зарегистрировать VM как синглтон, который раз создается и больше не удаляется. Ну а так, как я вам уже ссылками выше намекнул, убирайте из XAML `DataContext` и храните их отдельно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мы с вами посмотрели, а `get => null` никто не заметил. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только сейчас заметил `get => null;`. Что должно происходить, если вы что бы не происходило, отдаете `null`?

```
internal class ViewMainModal : ViewModelChangings
{
    private page _curPage = new MainPage();

    public Page CurPage
    {
        get => _curPage;
        set => Set(ref _curPage, value);
    }

    public ICommand OpenStartPage { get; } = new RelayCommand(() => CurPage = new StartPage());
    public ICommand OpenDiagnosticPage { get; } = new RelayCommand(() => CurPage = new DiagnosticPage());
    public ICommand OpenMainPage { get; } = new RelayCommand(() => CurPage = new MainPage());
}
```

Но вообще `Frame+Page` не подходят для нормального использования в MVVM, поэтому я бы рекомендовал [другое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567).

*Я переименовал свойство, чтобы избежать путаницы, не забудьте `Content="{Binding CurPage}"` поправить в XAML.*